# Vue.js rendering issue, responsive iframes

Tags: iframe, vue.js, responsive

I am trying to pull some videos from Vimeo with Vue and the component markup is this:

```
<div class="vimeo-data">
  <div class="video-wrap" v-for="video in videos" v-bind:key="video.name">
    <h2>{{video.name}}</h2>
    <figure v-html="video.embed.html" class="video-container"></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my understanding, this should generate a HTML similar to this (which it does).

```
<div class="vimeo-data">
  <div class="video-wrap">
    <h2>The video name</h2>
    <figure v-html="video.embed.html" class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/249865075?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0" width="1920" height="810" frameborder="0" title="Academia Titi Aur  - Macadam" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="video-wrap">
    <h2>Another video name</h2>
    <figure class="video-container">
      <iframe allowFullScreen frameborder="0" width="100%" height="564" mozallowfullscreen src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/249865062" webkitAllowFullScreen></iframe>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="video-wrap" >
    <h2>Some video name</h2>
    <figure class="video-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/249226102?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0&autopause=0&player_id=0" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" title="6 PLIN intro" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made a test and created a static html page with what is being generated by Vue and although the css is the same (below) the videos in the static html are nice and responsive (https://jsfiddle.net/4q5Lyn97/) while the ones generated by Vue are not responsive, they seem cut - see the image below.[image]

```
.vimeo-data {
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
 }
 embed,
 iframe,
 object {
    max-width: 100%;
 }
 .video-wrap {
     padding-top: 2em;
     max-width: 98%;
     margin: 10px auto;
     clear: both;
 }
 .video-container {
     position: relative;
     padding-bottom: 42.18%;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
 }
 .video-container iframe,
 .video-container object,
 .video-container embed {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
 }
```

What can be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Show the JS code for that Vue instance, so we can reproduce. All videos in that JSFiddle seem fine (they are, right?). I'm not seeing what is not OK.

Comment: `iframes` are unlikely responsive.